# TF-Slim can't exclude variables when import data from checkpoint files

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

Though i exclude variables that don't exist in the checkpoint file,the program still try to find them in the checkpoint.The func

```
 variables_to_restore = slim.get_variables_to_restore(exclude=exclude_set)
```

is really confusing me. Anyone can help me?

```
     with tf.Graph().as_default():
    tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
    images, labels, bboxs, origin_sizes = read_content_recorder.get_image_batch(voc_dataset_dir, batch_size=50,
                                                                                reshape_size=[image_size, image_size],
                                                                                category_num=20,
                                                                                num_shards=_NUM_SHARDS,
                                                                                category="train")

    image_batch = tf.stack(images, axis=0)
    label_batch = tf.stack(labels, axis=0)

    with slim.arg_scope(vgg.vgg_arg_scope()):
        logits, _ = vgg.vgg_16(image_batch, num_classes=20, is_training=True)

    exclude_set = ['matching_filenames',
                   'vgg_16 / fc6 / weights',
                   'vgg_16 / fc6 / biases',
                   'vgg_16 / fc7 / weights',
                   'vgg_16 / fc7 / biases',
                   'vgg_16 / fc8 / weights',
                   'vgg_16 / fc8 / biases',
                   'vgg_16 / conv1 / conv1_1 / weights / Momentum',
                   'vgg_16 / conv1 / conv1_1 / biases / Momentum',
                   'vgg_16 / conv1 / conv1_2 / weights / Momentum',
                   'vgg_16 / conv1 / conv1_2 / biases / Momentum',
                   'vgg_16 / conv2 / conv2_1 / weights / Momentum',
                   'vgg_16 / conv2 /conv2_1/biases/Momentum',
                   'vgg_16 / conv2 /conv2_2/weights/Momentum',
                   'vgg_16 / conv2 /conv2_2/biases/Momentum',
                   'vgg_16 / conv3 /conv3_1/weights/Momentum',
                   'vgg_16 / conv3 /conv3_1/biases/Momentum',
                   'vgg_16 / conv3 /conv3_2/weights/Momentum',
                   'vgg_16 / conv3 /conv3_2/biases/Momentum',
                   'vgg_16 / conv3 /conv3_3/ weights/Momentum',
                   'vgg_16 / conv3 /conv3_3 / biases/Momentum',
                   'vgg_16 / conv4 /conv4_1 / weights/Momentum',
                   'vgg_16 / conv4 /conv4_1 / biases/Momentum',
                   'vgg_16 / conv4 /conv4_2 / weights/Momentum',
                   'vgg_16 / conv4 /conv4_2 / biases/Momentum',
                   'vgg_16 / conv4 /conv4_3 / weights/Momentum',
                   'vgg_16 / conv4 /conv4_3 / biases/Momentum',
                   'vgg_16 / conv5 /conv5_1 / weights/Momentum',
                   'vgg_16 / conv5 /conv5_1 / biases/Momentum',
                   'vgg_16 / conv5 /conv5_2 / weights/Momentum',
                   'vgg_16 / conv5 /conv5_2 / biases/Momentum',
                   'vgg_16 / conv5 /conv5_3 / weights/Momentum',
                   'vgg_16 / conv5 /conv5_3 / biases/Momentum',
                   'vgg_16 / fc6 /weights / Momentum',
                   'vgg_16 / fc6 /biases / Momentum',
                   'vgg_16 / fc7 /weights / Momentum',
                   'vgg_16 / fc7 /biases / Momentum',
                   'vgg_16 / fc8 /weights / Momentum',
                   'vgg_16 / fc8 /biases / Momentum']

    variables_to_restore = slim.get_variables_to_restore(exclude=exclude_set)

    for e in variables_to_restore:
        print e.name
    # variables_to_restore print result:
    # vgg_16 / conv1 / conv1_1 / weights:0
    # vgg_16 / conv1 / conv1_1 / biases:0
    # vgg_16 / conv1 / conv1_2 / weights:0
    # vgg_16 / conv1 / conv1_2 / biases:0
    # vgg_16 / conv2 / conv2_1 / weights:0
    # vgg_16 / conv2 / conv2_1 / biases:0
    # vgg_16 / conv2 / conv2_2 / weights:0
    # vgg_16 / conv2 / conv2_2 / biases:0
    # vgg_16 / conv3 / conv3_1 / weights:0
    # vgg_16 / conv3 / conv3_1 / biases:0
    # vgg_16 / conv3 / conv3_2 / weights:0
    # vgg_16 / conv3 / conv3_2 / biases:0
    # vgg_16 / conv3 / conv3_3 / weights:0
    # vgg_16 / conv3 / conv3_3 / biases:0
    # vgg_16 / conv4 / conv4_1 / weights:0
    # vgg_16 / conv4 / conv4_1 / biases:0
    # vgg_16 / conv4 / conv4_2 / weights:0
    # vgg_16 / conv4 / conv4_2 / biases:0
    # vgg_16 / conv4 / conv4_3 / weights:0
    # vgg_16 / conv4 / conv4_3 / biases:0
    # vgg_16 / conv5 / conv5_1 / weights:0
    # vgg_16 / conv5 / conv5_1 / biases:0
    # vgg_16 / conv5 / conv5_2 / weights:0
    # vgg_16 / conv5 / conv5_2 / biases:0
    # vgg_16 / conv5 / conv5_3 / weights:0
    # vgg_16 / conv5 / conv5_3 / biases:0
    # vgg_16 / fc6 / weights:0
    # vgg_16 / fc6 / biases:0
    # vgg_16 / fc7 / weights:0
    # vgg_16 / fc7 / biases:0
    # vgg_16 / fc8 / weights:0
    # vgg_16 / fc8 / biases:0

    global_step = slim.model_variable('global_step', initializer=tf.constant(0), dtype=tf.int32)
    learning_rate = slim.train.exponential_decay(0.01, global_step, 10000, 0.1, staircase=True)

    predictions = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
    loss = slim.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(predictions, label_batch)

    total_loss = slim.losses.get_total_loss()
    tf.summary.scalar('losses/Total Loss', total_loss)

    optimizer = slim.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate,momentum=0.9)
    train_op = slim.learning.create_train_op(total_loss, optimizer)

    pretrained_model_path = "./pretrained/vgg_16.ckpt"
    #pretrained model parameters:
    #inspect_checkpoint.print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file(pretrained_model_path, '', False)


    # print "my variables"
    # for e in slim.get_variables():
    #     print e.name

    # matching_filenames:0
    # vgg_16 / conv1 / conv1_1 / weights:0
    # vgg_16 / conv1 / conv1_1 / biases:0
    # vgg_16 / conv1 / conv1_2 / weights:0
    # vgg_16 / conv1 / conv1_2 / biases:0
    # vgg_16 / conv2 / conv2_1 / weights:0
    # vgg_16 / conv2 / conv2_1 / biases:0
    # vgg_16 / conv2 / conv2_2 / weights:0
    # vgg_16 / conv2 / conv2_2 / biases:0
    # vgg_16 / conv3 / conv3_1 / weights:0
    # vgg_16 / conv3 / conv3_1 / biases:0
    # vgg_16 / conv3 / conv3_2 / weights:0
    # vgg_16 / conv3 / conv3_2 / biases:0
    # vgg_16 / conv3 / conv3_3 / weights:0
    # vgg_16 / conv3 / conv3_3 / biases:0
    # vgg_16 / conv4 / conv4_1 / weights:0
    # vgg_16 / conv4 / conv4_1 / biases:0
    # vgg_16 / conv4 / conv4_2 / weights:0
    # vgg_16 / conv4 / conv4_2 / biases:0
    # vgg_16 / conv4 / conv4_3 / weights:0
    # vgg_16 / conv4 / conv4_3 / biases:0
    # vgg_16 / conv5 / conv5_1 / weights:0
    # vgg_16 / conv5 / conv5_1 / biases:0
    # vgg_16 / conv5 / conv5_2 / weights:0
    # vgg_16 / conv5 / conv5_2 / biases:0
    # vgg_16 / conv5 / conv5_3 / weights:0
    # vgg_16 / conv5 / conv5_3 / biases:0
    # vgg_16 / fc6 / weights:0
    # vgg_16 / fc6 / biases:0
    # vgg_16 / fc7 / weights:0
    # vgg_16 / fc7 / biases:0
    # vgg_16 / fc8 / weights:0
    # vgg_16 / fc8 / biases:0
    # global_step:0
    # vgg_16 / conv1 / conv1_1 / weights / Momentum:0
    # vgg_16 / conv1 / conv1_1 / biases / Momentum:0
    # vgg_16 / conv1 / conv1_2 / weights / Momentum:0
    # vgg_16 / conv1 / conv1_2 / biases / Momentum:0
    # vgg_16 / conv2 / conv2_1 / weights / Momentum:0
    # vgg_16 / conv2 / conv2_1 / biases / Momentum:0
    # vgg_16 / conv2 / conv2_2 / weights / Momentum:0
    # vgg_16 / conv2 / conv2_2 / biases / Momentum:0
    # vgg_16 / conv3 / conv3_1 / weights / Momentum:0
    # vgg_16 / conv3 / conv3_1 / biases / Momentum:0
    # vgg_16 / conv3 / conv3_2 / weights / Momentum:0
    # vgg_16 / conv3 / conv3_2 / biases / Momentum:0
    # vgg_16 / conv3 / conv3_3 / weights / Momentum:0
    # vgg_16 / conv3 / conv3_3 / biases / Momentum:0
    # vgg_16 / conv4 / conv4_1 / weights / Momentum:0
    # vgg_16 / conv4 / conv4_1 / biases / Momentum:0
    # vgg_16 / conv4 / conv4_2 / weights / Momentum:0
    # vgg_16 / conv4 / conv4_2 / biases / Momentum:0
    # vgg_16 / conv4 / conv4_3 / weights / Momentum:0
    # vgg_16 / conv4 / conv4_3 / biases / Momentum:0
    # vgg_16 / conv5 / conv5_1 / weights / Momentum:0
    # vgg_16 / conv5 / conv5_1 / biases / Momentum:0
    # vgg_16 / conv5 / conv5_2 / weights / Momentum:0
    # vgg_16 / conv5 / conv5_2 / biases / Momentum:0
    # vgg_16 / conv5 / conv5_3 / weights / Momentum:0
    # vgg_16 / conv5 / conv5_3 / biases / Momentum:0
    # vgg_16 / fc6 / weights / Momentum:0
    # vgg_16 / fc6 / biases / Momentum:0
    # vgg_16 / fc7 / weights / Momentum:0
    # vgg_16 / fc7 / biases / Momentum:0
    # vgg_16 / fc8 / weights / Momentum:0
    # vgg_16 / fc8 / biases / Momentum:0


    #init_fn = slim.assign_from_checkpoint_fn(pretrained_model_path, variables_to_restore)
    saver = tf.train.Saver(variables_to_restore)
    def init_fn(sess):
        saver.restore(sess)

    #saver = tf.train.Saver(variables_to_restore)

    final_loss = slim.learning.train(
        train_op,
        global_step=global_step,
        init_fn=init_fn,
        logdir=train_log_dir,  # model checkpoints and summaries be written here
        saver = saver,#
        number_of_steps=370000  # training steps
    )
```

Run info is below,it shows the program can't find the Momentum nodes while i exclude them in my code.I try to make saver but it seems unrelated

```
TFRecord files did exist!Go to next stage....

Instructions for updating:
Use tf.losses.get_regularization_losses instead.
INFO:tensorflow:Summary name losses/Total Loss is illegal; using losses/Total_Loss instead.
['matching_filenames', 'vgg_16/fc6/weights', 'vgg_16/fc6/biases', 'vgg_16/fc7/weights', 'vgg_16/fc7/biases', 'vgg_16/fc8/weights', 'vgg_16/fc8/biases', 'vgg_16/conv1/conv1_1/weights/Momentum', 'vgg_16/conv1/conv1_1/biases/Momentum', 'vgg_16/conv1/conv1_2/weights/Momentum', 'vgg_16/conv1/conv1_2/biases/Momentum', 'vgg_16/conv2/conv2_1/weights/Momentum', 'vgg_16/conv2/conv2_1/biases/Momentum', 'vgg_16/conv2/conv2_2/weights/Momentum', 'vgg_16/conv2/conv2_2/biases/Momentum', 'vgg_16/conv3/conv3_1/weights/Momentum', 'vgg_16/conv3/conv3_1/biases/Momentum', 'vgg_16/conv3/conv3_2/weights/Momentum', 'vgg_16/conv3/conv3_2/biases/Momentum', 'vgg_16/conv3/conv3_3/weights/Momentum', 'vgg_16/conv3/conv3_3/biases/Momentum', 'vgg_16/conv4/conv4_1/weights/Momentum', 'vgg_16/conv4/conv4_1/biases/Momentum', 'vgg_16/conv4/conv4_2/weights/Momentum', 'vgg_16/conv4/conv4_2/biases/Momentum', 'vgg_16/conv4/conv4_3/weights/Momentum', 'vgg_16/conv4/conv4_3/biases/Momentum', 'vgg_16/conv5/conv5_1/weights/Momentum', 'vgg_16/conv5/conv5_1/biases/Momentum', 'vgg_16/conv5/conv5_2/weights/Momentum', 'vgg_16/conv5/conv5_2/biases/Momentum', 'vgg_16/conv5/conv5_3/weights/Momentum', 'vgg_16/conv5/conv5_3/biases/Momentum', 'vgg_16/fc6/weights/Momentum', 'vgg_16/fc6/biases/Momentum', 'vgg_16/fc7/weights/Momentum', 'vgg_16/fc7/biases/Momentum', 'vgg_16/fc8/weights/Momentum', 'vgg_16/fc8/biases/Momentum']
27
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 960M
major: 5 minor: 0 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.176
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 3.95GiB
Free memory: 3.52GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:906] DMA: 0 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:916] 0:   Y 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 960M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv1/conv1_1/weights/Momentum not found in checkpoint
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv3/conv3_3/weights/Momentum not found in checkpoint
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv1/conv1_1/weights/Momentum not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2_5 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_1/Const_0, save_1/RestoreV2_5/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2_5/shape_and_slices)]]
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/fc8/weights/Momentum not found in checkpoint
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv1/conv1_1/weights/Momentum not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2_5 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_1/Const_0, save_1/RestoreV2_5/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2_5/shape_and_slices)]]
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv1/conv1_2/biases/Momentum not found in checkpoint
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv1/conv1_1/weights/Momentum not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2_5 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_1/Const_0, save_1/RestoreV2_5/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2_5/shape_and_slices)]]
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv1/conv1_1/weights/Momentum not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2_5 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_1/Const_0, save_1/RestoreV2_5/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2_5/shape_and_slices)]]
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv1/conv1_1/weights/Momentum not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2_5 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_1/Const_0, save_1/RestoreV2_5/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2_5/shape_and_slices)]]
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv1/conv1_2/weights/Momentum not found in checkpoint
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv2/conv2_1/biases/Momentum not found in checkpoint
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv1/conv1_1/weights/Momentum not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2_5 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_1/Const_0, save_1/RestoreV2_5/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2_5/shape_and_slices)]]
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv1/conv1_1/weights/Momentum not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2_5 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_1/Const_0, save_1/RestoreV2_5/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2_5/shape_and_slices)]]
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv1/conv1_1/weights/Momentum not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2_5 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_1/Const_0, save_1/RestoreV2_5/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2_5/shape_and_slices)]]
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv4/conv4_1/biases/Momentum not found in checkpoint
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv1/conv1_1/weights/Momentum not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2_5 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_1/Const_0, save_1/RestoreV2_5/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2_5/shape_and_slices)]]
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv2/conv2_1/weights/Momentum not found in checkpoint
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv2/conv2_2/biases/Momentum not found in checkpoint
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv4/conv4_1/weights/Momentum not found in checkpoint
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/fc8/biases/Momentum not found in checkpoint
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv4/conv4_2/biases/Momentum not found in checkpoint
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv1/conv1_1/weights/Momentum not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2_5 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_1/Const_0, save_1/RestoreV2_5/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2_5/shape_and_slices)]]
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv1/conv1_1/weights/Momentum not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2_5 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_1/Const_0, save_1/RestoreV2_5/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2_5/shape_and_slices)]]
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv2/conv2_2/weights/Momentum not found in checkpoint
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv1/conv1_1/weights/Momentum not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2_5 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_1/Const_0, save_1/RestoreV2_5/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2_5/shape_and_slices)]]
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv4/conv4_3/weights/Momentum not found in checkpoint
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv1/conv1_1/weights/Momentum not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2_5 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_1/Const_0, save_1/RestoreV2_5/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2_5/shape_and_slices)]]
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv1/conv1_1/weights/Momentum not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2_5 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_1/Const_0, save_1/RestoreV2_5/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2_5/shape_and_slices)]]
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv1/conv1_1/weights/Momentum not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2_5 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_1/Const_0, save_1/RestoreV2_5/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2_5/shape_and_slices)]]
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv1/conv1_1/weights/Momentum not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2_5 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_1/Const_0, save_1/RestoreV2_5/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2_5/shape_and_slices)]]
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv1/conv1_1/weights/Momentum not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2_5 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_1/Const_0, save_1/RestoreV2_5/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2_5/shape_and_slices)]]
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv5/conv5_2/biases/Momentum not found in checkpoint
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv5/conv5_1/weights/Momentum not found in checkpoint
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv5/conv5_1/biases/Momentum not found in checkpoint
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv1/conv1_1/weights/Momentum not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2_5 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_1/Const_0, save_1/RestoreV2_5/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2_5/shape_and_slices)]]
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv5/conv5_3/biases/Momentum not found in checkpoint
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv5/conv5_2/weights/Momentum not found in checkpoint
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv5/conv5_3/weights/Momentum not found in checkpoint
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv1/conv1_1/biases/Momentum not found in checkpoint
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv1/conv1_1/weights/Momentum not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2_5 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_1/Const_0, save_1/RestoreV2_5/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2_5/shape_and_slices)]]
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/fc6/biases/Momentum not found in checkpoint
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv1/conv1_1/weights/Momentum not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2_5 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_1/Const_0, save_1/RestoreV2_5/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2_5/shape_and_slices)]]
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv1/conv1_1/weights/Momentum not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2_5 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_1/Const_0, save_1/RestoreV2_5/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2_5/shape_and_slices)]]
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv1/conv1_1/weights/Momentum not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2_5 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_1/Const_0, save_1/RestoreV2_5/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2_5/shape_and_slices)]]
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/fc6/weights/Momentum not found in checkpoint
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv1/conv1_1/weights/Momentum not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2_5 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_1/Const_0, save_1/RestoreV2_5/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2_5/shape_and_slices)]]
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv1/conv1_1/weights/Momentum not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2_5 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_1/Const_0, save_1/RestoreV2_5/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2_5/shape_and_slices)]]
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/fc7/biases/Momentum not found in checkpoint
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/fc7/weights/Momentum not found in checkpoint
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv3/conv3_1/biases/Momentum not found in checkpoint
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv3/conv3_1/weights/Momentum not found in checkpoint
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key vgg_16/conv1/conv1_1/weights/Momentum not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2_5 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_1/Const_0, save_1/RestoreV2_5/tensor_names, save_1/Restore_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_1/Const_0, save_1/RestoreV2_5/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2_5/shape_and_slices)]]
INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError'>, Key vgg_16/conv1/conv1_1/weights/Momentum not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2_5 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_1/Const_0, save_1/RestoreV2_5/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2_5/shape_and_slices)]]
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2_57/_11 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_211_save_1/RestoreV2_57", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]

Caused by op u'save_1/RestoreV2_5', defined at:
  File "/home/wuzheng/PycharmProjects/localization/test2.py", line 133, in <module>
    number_of_steps=370000  # training steps
  File "/home/wuzheng/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py", line 688, in train
    saver = saver or tf_saver.Saver()
  File "/home/wuzheng/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1040, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "/home/wuzheng/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1070, in build
    restore_sequentially=self._restore_sequentially)
  File "/home/wuzheng/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 675, in build
    restore_sequentially, reshape)
  File "/home/wuzheng/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 402, in _AddRestoreOps
    tensors = self.restore_op(filename_tensor, saveable, preferred_shard)
  File "/home/wuzheng/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 242, in restore_op
    [spec.tensor.dtype])[0])
  File "/home/wuzheng/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py", line 668, in restore_v2
    dtypes=dtypes, name=name)
  File "/home/wuzheng/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 763, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/wuzheng/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2327, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/wuzheng/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1226, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Key vgg_16/conv1/conv1_1/weights/Momentum not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2_5 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_1/Const_0, save_1/RestoreV2_5/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2_5/shape_and_slices)]]
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2_57/_11 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_211_save_1/RestoreV2_57", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wuzheng/PycharmProjects/localization/test2.py", line 133, in <module>
    number_of_steps=370000  # training steps
  File "/home/wuzheng/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py", line 776, in train
    master, start_standard_services=False, config=session_config) as sess:
  File "/home/wuzheng/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "/home/wuzheng/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 960, in managed_session
    self.stop(close_summary_writer=close_summary_writer)
  File "/home/wuzheng/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 788, in stop
    stop_grace_period_secs=self._stop_grace_secs)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Can you please clarify which variables from VGG16 are you trying to exclude? Your code for building the exclude_set and include_set is really not clear to me

Comment: Thank you,I have updated my code.

Comment: Look at my answer. See where I put the `variables_to_restore` definition? That has to go **before** your `global_step` definition, and right above that you must define your `exclude_set`. Please do that and post the result of `print(variables_to_restore)`

Comment: Well,i have renewed the result.

Comment: See the Update in my answer

Comment: I try it and the problem is the same.The code is updated.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas. My suggestion is to try with an empty `exclude_set`, see if that raises a different error and move from there. Maybe tensorflow doesn't like if you pass an exclude set with variables that are not defined?

Comment: I'm sorry i just forget to add saver to train.But the new problem is 'momentum' variables are not initialized

Comment: throw a `sess.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer()])` in your `init_fn` and see if that helps

Comment: When i use tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer instead of  MomentumOptimizer,the exclude is useful and i can exclude 'fc6/7/8' and my own 'matching_files' nodes.

Comment: After running initializer,the problem is the same,some parameters are not initialized.

Comment: Hi, i removed all files in train_log_dir which was  to keep saved model and summary log created by slim.learning.train and retrain my model, it work at the first time.If i run it second time,it show 'momentum' uninitialized.Again i remove saver=tf.train.Saver(variables_to_restore) in my code and run my code,it finally works.In my opinion,the slim.learning.train was created by tf.supervisor,the supervisor can continue training process in the last ending time,if i retrain my model while i didn't keep all variables then it will raise uninitialized error.

Comment: BTW.whether to  define variables_to_restore after or before my own variables doesn't matter,they all  work correctly.

Comment: And why it will work after i removed train_log_dir in the first time.Similar to above,supervisor seem to continue according to training log.But i didn't save 'momentum' variables.And why i first raise this question,i can't remember what i saved firstly,maybe the saved model is a bug.I run the code twice and set number_of_steps 1000 and 1100 separately,the first stage global_step shows 0~1000 and the second global_step shows 1000~1100.So you see the code continunes last process automatically.

Comment: In the third time,i set num_of_steps=1200 and slim.assign_from_checkpoint_fn(train_log_dir, variables_to_restore) which replaces pretrained_model_dir with saved_model_dir,it work the same with the second stage and begin at 1101.So superviors maybe firstly check checkpoint-file,if None,reading from pretrain_model,else,reading from saved_model.It is amazing!

Answer (score 0):

Move the computation of the exclude set right after you define the network (and before you add any other variable to your graph). That way, the list of variables restored will match the checkpoint and you won't have to bother manually excluding every new variable you defined (for example your Momentum):

```py
with slim.arg_scope(vgg.vgg_arg_scope()):
    logits, _ = vgg.vgg_16(image_batch, num_classes=20, is_training=True)
exclude_set = ['MyVariableToExclude', 'MyOtherVarialeToExclude']
variables_to_restore = slim.get_variables_to_restore(exclude = exclude_set)

[optimizer definition and stuff]

saver = tf.train.Saver(variables_to_restore)

[in your session]

saver.restore(sess, checkpoint_file)
```

### Update:

Instead of `init_fn = slim.assign_from_checkpoint_fn(pretrained_model_path, variables_to_restore)` try this:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(variables_to_restore)
def init_fn(sess):
    saver.restore(sess)
```

and change your call to `slim.learning.train` as such (note that there is no actual difference from your call to the function, but the `init_fn` parameter is now the function we defined above):

```
final_loss = slim.learning.train(
        train_op,
        global_step=global_step,
        init_fn=init_fn,
        logdir=train_log_dir,
        number_of_steps=370000  # training steps
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.I code again according to your advice.
        with slim.arg_scope(vgg.vgg_arg_scope()):
            logits, _ = vgg.vgg_16(image_batch, num_classes=20, is_training=True)
        [exclude_computation]
        variables_to_restore
        optimizer
        saver
        final_loss = slim.learning.train(saver,init_fn)
while there is another problem,i can't initialize other tensors outside saver.If i move saver,the problem is same as original,the program still try to find 'Momentum'.I'm confused with the TF-Slim framework.

Comment: Please add that code as an update to you question, in a comment code is not structured and thus not readable.