# Excluding slim.assign_from_checkpoint searching for Momentum variables

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-slim

I am trying to finetune [vgg_16](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/vgg.py) model with the  [Momentum Optimizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/MomentumOptimizer) . For this, I use the pretrained models from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim).

Before finetuning, I assign the varible values from the models as following,

```
variables_to_restore = slim.get_variables_to_restore(exclude=["vgg_16/fc8"])
init_assign_op, init_feed_dict = slim.assign_from_checkpoint(model_path, variables_to_restore)
```

Note, I do not exclude the `vgg_16/*/*/Momentum` variables. Hence I recieve an error,

```
ValueError: Checkpoint is missing variable [vgg_16/conv1/conv1_1/weights/Momentum],
```

as expected.

My problem is that including all the Momentum variables in the exlude list very cumbersome([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45877948/tf-slim-cant-exclude-variables-when-import-data-from-checkpoint-files)). Is there an smarter way to exclude just the Momentum variables?

This is important since manual enterring of exclusions is impossible for large models such as resnet.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I solved this problem by using optimizer_slot_variables = optimizer.get_slot_names() .

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem by using this code:

```
def _init_fn():


    variables_to_restore = []
      for var in slim.get_model_variables():
        excluded = False
        for exclusion in exclusions:
          if var.op.name.startswith(exclusion):
            excluded = True
            break
        if not excluded:
          variables_to_restore.append(var)

      if tf.gfile.IsDirectory(FLAGS.checkpoint_path):
        checkpoint_path = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(FLAGS.checkpoint_path)
      else:
        checkpoint_path = FLAGS.checkpoint_path

      tf.logging.info('Fine-tuning from %s' % checkpoint_path)

      return slim.assign_from_checkpoint_fn(
          checkpoint_path,
          variables_to_restore,
    ignore_missing_vars=FLAGS.ignore_missing_vars)
```

use this function in `slim.learning.train(init_fn=init_fn,)`